# .on() taking text input to produce another input label and form field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to take input through a form, to produce another input field.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.button').click(function(){
        var value = $('#value').val();

        $(document).on('click', '.button', function(){
            $('#form1').append('<input type="text" id="value" value="'        + value + '"><button class="button">Enter</button>');
        });

        return false;
    }); 
});
```

This produces no error in Chrome console, though it errors in JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/yfjda40e/

What are the errors I am not catching?

Comment: Line no. 2  $('.button').click(function() {...});  you  can't assign event handlers directly to an element not created yet.

Comment: you didn't include `jquery` in jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Use [`Event delegation`](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) and `e.preventDefault()` to prevent default behavior of `button`

```js
$(document).on('click', '.button', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var value = $('#value').val();
  $('#form1').append('<input type="text" id="value" value="' + value + '"><button class="button">Enter</button>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
  <h1>Add field</h1>
  <form id='form1' action="" method='POST'>
    <input type="text" id="value" value="new value">
    <button class="button">Enter</button>
  </form>
</div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

### [**Fiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/yfjda40e/1/)